# how to populate user field with current user in django models via forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

hi i am working on a django app. functionality that i am implementing is to let my user buy a internet pack from the website.

i have implemented the model, view, template and url so far. but in the form i am getting a drop down list of all the users registered on the app. i automatically want django to link the user with current logged in user and let him select the pack he wants to buy and populate the model(table) automatically.

**My models.py**

```
def get_deadline():
    return dt.today() + timedelta(days=30)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Plans(models.Model):
    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.plan_name


class Orders(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    pack = models.ForeignKey(Plans, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=get_deadline())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        name = str(self.user.username)
        return name
```

**my views.py**

```
class UserBuyPlan(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template = 'plans/plan.html'
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('autos:all')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home-home')

    def get(self, request):
        form = BuyPlanForm()
        ctx = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template, ctx)

    def post(self, request):
        form = BuyPlanForm(request.CustomUser,request.POST)
        if not form.is_valid():
            ctx = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template, ctx)

        make = form.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

**my forms.py** (i tried searching online and found this ****init**** implementation but it doesnt work)

```
class BuyPlanForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.user = CustomUser
        super(BuyPlanForm, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].initial = self.user
```

the photo of resulting form is attached below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so i found the answer.
just had to change my view function a bit.
if you want a detailed tutorial then please visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s7e_Fy6NRU&t=1840s
he explains in a much better way.

```
class UserBuyPlan(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Orders
    template_name = 'plans/plan.html'
    fields = ['pack']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and also had to add absolute url method to my orders model

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    pack = models.ForeignKey(Plans, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=get_deadline())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        name = str(self.user.username)
        return name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home-home')
```

rest everything is same.